# jquery and strings from php code

Tags: php, jquery, progress-bar

I have a problem how to pass for example `$example=1;` variable to this jquery like a value in bracket where is 20, 40, 60.....:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $("#pb1").progressBar(20);
                $("#pb2").progressBar(40);
                $("#pb3").progressBar(60);
                $("#pb4").progressBar(70);
                $("#pb5").progressBar(100);
                $("#pb6").progressBar(100);

            });
    </script>
```

The main problem is that I want to example string have value from database, so that's why I need to make it outside of script.

Comment: `$("#pb1").progressBar(<?=$example?>);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%5Bjquery%5D+progress+bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this code is in your .php page...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $("#pb1").progressBar(<?php echo $pb1 ;?>);
                $("#pb2").progressBar(<?php echo $pb2 ;?>);
                $("#pb3").progressBar(<?php echo $pb3 ;?>);
                $("#pb4").progressBar(<?php echo $pb4 ;?>);
                $("#pb5").progressBar(<?php echo $pb5 ;?>);
                $("#pb6").progressBar(<?php echo $pb6 ;?>);

            });
    </script>
```

Where $pb1,$pb2,$pb3,$pb4,$pb5,$pb6 are Integers ..

Answer (score 1):

This is simple:

```
    <?php 
//Insert your code to generate the values to $example
$example = ...
?>

// and here is your JS with php code inside it

<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $("#pb1").progressBar(<?php echo $example; ?>);
                $("#pb2").progressBar(<?php echo $example1; ?>);
                $("#pb3").progressBar(<?php echo $example2; ?>);
                $("#pb4").progressBar(<?php echo $example3; ?>);
                $("#pb5").progressBar(<?php echo $example4; ?>);
                $("#pb6").progressBar(<?php echo $example5; ?>);

            });
    </script>
```

I hope it helps! Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to pass php variable to client to dynamically replace numbers in jquery you can use like code in below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $("#pb1").progressBar(<?php echo example;  ?>);


            });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, having it in your database does not mean you cannot do so in the script. There are in fact several ways to do that. You could have your javascript file be php that generates javascript instead of html, or perhaps easier: you could use inline javscript. However, if you do want to keep the two separated it is still possible:

```
[..]
<script type='text/javascript'>var percentageDone = <?php echo intval($example) ?>;</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#pb1").progressBar(percentageDone);

        });
</script>

[..]
```